# Instance of 'RootLogger' has no 'trace' member (but some types could not be inferred)

Tags: python, pylint

I have the following test script, which mimics what I usually do to setup an extended logger:

```
import logging

TRACE_LL      = 25
TRACE_LSTR    = 'TRACE'
LOG_FORMATTER = '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-10s - %(message)s'

class MyLogger(logging.Logger):

    def __init__(self, log_name):
        logging.Logger.__init__(self, log_name)
        self.setLevel(TRACE_LL)
        hdlr = logging.StreamHandler()
        formatter = logging.Formatter(LOG_FORMATTER)
        hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.addHandler(hdlr)

    def trace(self, txt, *args, **kwargs):
        self.log(TRACE_LL, txt, *args, **kwargs)

def getlog(name):
    return logging.getLogger(name)

def setup():
    logging.setLoggerClass(MyLogger)
    logging.addLevelName(TRACE_LL, TRACE_LSTR)
setup()

log = getlog('mylog')
log.trace('Trace this')
```

Running this works as expected:

```
2014-01-07 07:22:59,982 - TRACE      - Trace this
```

But running `pylint` on this causes trouble:

```
» pylint -E getlog_test.py
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module getlog_test
E: 29,0: Instance of 'RootLogger' has no 'trace' member (but some types could not be inferred)
```

I get hundreds of those messages in my codebase, because I am using logging extensively.

How can I solve the pylint error?

As an alternative, disabling it would also be enough, but only for the `RootLogger` instance: I still want to know if other parts of the code have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Although I find pylint valuable, in my experience, it produces many false warnings and errors.  You can disable one or more checks for any lines of your code by surrounding that code with comments of the form:

```
# pylint: disable=E1103
code that pylint trips over
# pylint: enable=E1103
```

where E1103 is the error to be suppressed.  You can suppress multiple errors the same way with a comma-separated list of error codes.  Pylint's documentation on this is [here](http://docs.pylint.org/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message).

Comment: Thanks, I am testing this. The error code for my problem is `E1103` (`pylint --list-msgs | grep "but some types could not be inferred"`)

Comment: @gonvaled Thanks.  I updated the error number and added a link to pylint's documentation of this feature.

Comment: I have tested this. I can disable it on the command line with `--disable E1103`, but it is not possible to disable it selectively for the affected module (my logger module) I would need to instrument all files using my logger with `# pylint: disable=E1103`, which is not feasible, and would also mask other errors not related to `RootLogger`. So currently, using the command line `--disable` flag, the error message gets globally disabled, for `RootLogger` **and** other affected classes, which I wanted to avoid. But I guess I'll have to live with this for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Pylint is not smart enough to grasp that you'll get `MyLogger` instances on calling `getLogger`.

Beside using inline enabling/disabling of messages, which is easier at first, you may want to take a look at the pylint-brain project (https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint-brain).

You'll find there how to write a little astroid plugin that could add a 'trace' method to default logging loggers (or even better, inform that `logging.getLogger()` return `MyLogger` instance but that is a bit more tricky).

This is definitly better in the long run.